# ansible double loops execute one by one based on when condition

Tags: ansible-playbook

In ansible variables are getting dynamically from register output
first loop will collect the values from registered ouput result and once it will satisfy the when condition, next loop should start the execution.
how to use two loops in one when condition in ansible

```
- name: stop the http service
 command: sh http.sh stop {{item}}
 args:
   chdir: /opt/http/
 loop: “{{http.stdout_lines}}”
 when: “item.stdout != 0"
 loop: “{{wordcount.results}}”
```

this is the code
but i unable to use two loops continuous
if one loop complete it should run next loop

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it will not work the way you want it to. You can only define the `loop` once per task; the second definition will be ignored. You might need to break this into multiple tasks, however, I can't propose a solution because its not entirely clear from your example on what you are trying to accomplish. More context might help.